# Distributed shared objects in multiple Java Virtual Machines

Tags: java

How can a distributed shared object implement in Java? By Distributed Shared object I mean, the full object graph shared across multiple JVM in the same machine and also across different machines, for example.

Support I have this object:

```java
Environment env = Environments.newInstance(dbPath, config);
environmentMap.put(dbPath, env);
```

Where `dbPath` is a path to a mounted network file system (e.g. `/mnt/db`). And I have 3 Linux machines running with such `dbPath` mounted on it on the same mount point.

I need this `env` object shared across different JVM and machines. Typically on a single JVM one strategy is to put this into a Singleton object and get the `Environment` object from that singleton. However, that obviously would not work on separate JVM let alone JVM on different machines.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You seem to be looking for RMI.

Comment: Wouldn't database be a better solution? You could have in-memory or standalone database and ORM (optionally)

Comment: @Progman in my case, the `Environment` object is not `Serializable` at all